# How to pass different credential in invoke-sqlcmd PowerShell

Tags: mysql, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm connecting my SQL Server database in my PowerShell Script like this

```
$serverName = "ServerName"
$DB = "DBName" 
$result = invoke-sqlcmd -query "select * FROM Table1" -database $DB -serverinstance $servername
```

but it's using my WIndow Authentication to login to my SQL Database and it's working fine but I'm wondering how can I pass different credential to login and do the query.

I have tried like this

```
$dbData = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Credential $psCred

$dbData = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Username $adminUPN -Password $pwd


$pwd = read-host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Password"  
$hello = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM Table1;" -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $DB -Username "Username" -Password $pwd
```

but It's always saying "Login failed for user 'username'"

I have already tried with a user that have access to the db but I'm still getting that error. Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to have your creds exposed on the command-line. The below works, though I'm wondering if you're trying to do Windows Auth instead of SQL Server Authentication. Username and Password is used for SQL Auth of accounts stored in the server and must have Mixed Mode enabled. Windows Auth is only supported for the account doing the connection (AKA, your PowerShell session).

```
$Creds = Get-Credential
$hello = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM Table1;" -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $DB -Credential $Creds
```